# Sum aggregated value django ORM

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I have a very simple database with two classes:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Address(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='addresses')
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the sum of quantity grouping by the number of addresses for each contact, so I get the sum of quantity for all contacts that have 0 addresses, the sum of quantity for all contacts that have 1 address and so on. This is what I have tried so far:

```
Contacto.objects.all() \
            .annotate(num_contact=Count('nombre')) \
            .values('num_contact','addresses__quantity') \
            .annotate(sum_quantity=Sum('addresses__quantity'))
```

but no luck, I'm not even sure I can do it with ORM